# Xtext tutorial - generated code contains errors :(

Tags: eclipse, xtext

Working through the five minute Xtext tutorial (http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/2_1_0/010-xtext-in-5-minutes.php)

I get to "Generating The Language Infrastructure" (which has really only required a few clicks and I find that the generated code contains errors...  in particular the class AbstractMyDslRuntimeModule throws the errors

- org.xtext.example.mydsl.serializer cannot be resolved to a type
- Class cannot be resolved to a type

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm trialing a lot of language development environments and they appear to interfere with each other - downloading a separate eclipse and using that only for xtext has solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would check whether the mentioned package exists in the project. It should be in either the src, or the src-gen source folder.

If not, then it is possible, that the package variables in the language workflow file is incorrect. Check the mwe2 file next to the grammar file for package information.

Comment: Yeah - the 'serializer' package isn't there... but I'm really confused as to why it wouldn't generate with the rest of the code... :(

Comment: Does the workflow file contain a line like that: fragment = serializer.SerializerFragment {}? If not, that is missing. Otherwise, I would look at the various package names whether they are consistent.